# React - Functional Components - Click twice issue

Tags: reactjs

I have a number of checkboxes on a page, on the onClick it should call the function and set the relevant value to true or false, but i have to click it twice for the value to reflect on the page.

Could someone please tell me where i am going wrong?

Checkbox

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id="search1"
  name="search1"
  onClick={(e) => handleSearchPropRef(e)}
/>
```

Function

```
    const handleSearchPropRef = (e) => {
      const value = e.target.checked;
      setSearchPropRef(value);
    };
```

Comment: *(Unrelated: `onClick={handleSearchPropRef}` would be incrementally easier to read.)*

Comment: You forgot to bind `checked={searchPropRef}` (unless you deliberately want an uncontrolled checkbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code you don't set the `checked` value with anything, I'm assuming you have a `searchPropRef` boolean. If you are going to use `checked`, you should use `onChange` rather than `onClick`. If you have a *number of checkboxes* on the page, make sure they are all using unique ids, names and state values.

Here is a working example with two checkboxes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tfjeiz?file=src%2FApp.js

```js
const [searchPropRef1, setSearchPropRef1] = useState(false);
const [searchPropRef2, setSearchPropRef2] = useState(false);

const handleSearchPropRef1 = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.checked;
  setSearchPropRef1(value);
};
const handleSearchPropRef2 = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.checked;
  setSearchPropRef2(value);
};

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="search1"
        name="search1"
        checked={searchPropRef1}
        onChange={handleSearchPropRef1}
      />
      <label htmlFor="search1">Search1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="search2"
        name="search2"
        checked={searchPropRef2}
        onChange={handleSearchPropRef2}
      />
      <label htmlFor="search2">Search2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

You shouldn't need any callbacks to get some checkboxes working.